# Compiling the source code creates bigger files comparing w/ Ubuntu prebuilt packages, why?

Tags: compiling, debug

Am I doing anything wrong? I'm building some libraries from the source code, but the file sizes are much much bigger comparing w/ Ubuntu packages. Here is an example.

https://github.com/linuxwacom/libwacom
built w/ configure; make creates libwacom.so.2.6.1 (149,1 kB) and the same file in /usr/lib has only 41,8 kB. I assume debug version comes with postfix 'd', am I right - so what's wrong here? Ta.

Comment: Simple : `$ strip libwacom.so.2.6.1` .... or install with `make install-strip` if this "make option" is available.

Answer (score 9):

The shared library is stripped (with `dh_strip` in the package build rules, which in turn uses the `strip` command) when the package is built, and Link Time Optimisation (LTO) is also disabled.

You can see the source code for how this package is built [on Launchpad](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libwacom/tree/debian/rules?h=applied/ubuntu/hirsute). You can also see the source code for `dh_strip` for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What would be the command for stripping all binary (exec) files in /usr/locale at once?

Comment: I’d guess `find /usr/local/lib -type f -regex '*.\.(a|so)$' -exec strip \{} \;`. That will (hopefully) strip all static and dynamic libraries in `/usr/local/lib`.